# variable inside Cookie name

Tags: jquery, cookies

I tried inserting a variable in cookie name

```
jQuery.cookie("box'+ variablename +'","open", {expires: 365});
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You're mixing up your quotes.

Comment: Let's assume `variablename`'s value is the string `cookies`.  Do you want the result to be `box'cookies'` or `boxcookies`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
jQuery.cookie("box"+ variablename ,"open", {expires: 365});
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the a `"` before and after the `+`.

```
jQuery.cookie("box'"+ variablename + "'","open", {expires: 365});
//-----------------^-----------------^
```

Do you really want the `'` inside of the string?  You probably don't.  In that case lose the `'`s.

```
jQuery.cookie("box"+ variablename, "open", {expires: 365});
```

Answer (score 0):

the name of cookie you are trying to save will look like this

```
box'VariableName'
```

Remove the single parenthesis.